# finding a missing tags

Tags: python, xml, dom

i am would like to make a test on XML file to find the place where a specific TAG is missing ( the TAG 'Terminal'), but my test don't work well

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('c:\\test\mydoc.xml')
#printing the number of blocs in my xml file
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ACLineSegment') 


print('************')
for s in itemlist :
     if s.childNodes['Name'].value == 'Terminal':
         print s.childNodes['Name'].value
```

here is an exemple of my xml file:

```
 <ACLineSegment Name="T261"  Description="" aliasName="">
 <Link_Conducting PathB=""/>
<Terminal Name="T1" Description="" aliasName="">
<Link_Terminal PathB=""/>
</Terminal>
<Terminal Name="T2" Description="" aliasName="">
<Link_Terminal PathB=""/>
</Terminal>
</ACLineSegment>
<ACLineSegment Name="T262"  Description="" aliasName="">
<Link_Conducting PathB=""/>
<Terminal Name="T1" Description="" aliasName="">
<Link_Terminal PathB=""/>
</Terminal>
<Terminal Name="T2" Description="" aliasName="">
<Link_Terminal PathB=""/>
</Terminal>
    </ACLineSegment>

<ACLineSegment Name="T263"  Description="" aliasName="">
<Link_Conducting PathB=""/>
</ACLineSegment>
enter code here
```

Comment: What exactly does “don't work well” mean? It shows an error? Show us the error message. It doesn’t give the answer you expect? What do you expect, and what does it show?

Comment: yes, i got no answer from my test. what i am looking is to get the Name (ex: "T263") of the block who don't contain the Tag Terminal.

Comment: @user2586513: please edit your answer to include the information.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('c:\\test\mydoc.xml')
#printing the number of blocs in my xml file
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ACLineSegment') 

for item in itemlist:
    found = False
    for child in item.childNodes:
        if child.nodeName == 'Terminal':
            found = True
    if not found:
        print item.getAttribute('Name')
```

This code prints the value of the `Name` attribute of every `ACLineSegment` element that does not contain a `Terminal` element:

```
T263
```

**Edit:**
To be even more succint you could use:

```
for item in itemlist:
    if len([x for x in item.childNodes if x.nodeName == 'Terminal']) == 0:
        print item.getAttribute('Name')
```

This code is basically the same logic. The inner `[]` part is a python [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which are really useful.

It creates a list of all child nodes that are of type `Terminal`. If the length of that list is 0 then that item didn't have any.

Comment: thank you it work perfectely although i didn't got the second solution.

Comment: @user2586513 You should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) this answer if it helped you resolve your issue.